# Hibernate won't set foreign key to value of parent's primary key on insert

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 tables that have a hierarchical relationship:

**Page** (Grandmother)

```
    public class Page extends BaseDAO {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "page_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
      public Integer getPageId() {
        return this.pageId;
      }

      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "page", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
      @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      public Set<PageWell> getPageWells() {
        return this.pageWells;
      }
    }
```

**PageWell** (Mother)

```
    public class PageWell extends BaseDAO {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "page_well_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public int getPageWellId() {
           return this.pageWellId;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "page_id", nullable = false)
        public Page getPage() {
            return this.page;
        }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pageWell", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        public Set<PageComponentAttribute> getPageComponentAttributes() {
            return this.pageComponentAttributes;
        }
    }
```

**PageComponentAttribute** (Daughter)

```
    public class PageComponentAttribute extends BaseDAO {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "page_component_attribute_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getPageComponentAttributeId() {
           return this.pageComponentAttributeId;
        }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "page_well_id", nullable = false)
        public PageWell getPageWell() {
            return this.pageWell;
        }
    }
```

The primary keys for all three tables are AutoIncrement in MySQL.  The expected behavior is that when I save the **Page**, all **PageWell** objects get saved, and all **PageComponentAttribute** objects also get saved.

For some reason, it is working correctly for the Grandmonther -> Daughter relationship.  But in the case of the Mother -> Daughter relationship, the Daughter's foreign key is set to 0 every time.  This was obviously causing a constraint violation.  I have temporarily removed the FK constraint on that relationship, and the record makes it into the table, but the FK is still 0.

My save code looks like this:

```
    Page page = getPage(request);  //getPage() finds an instance of page, or creates and persists a new instance if none exists.
    Set<PageWell> wells = page.getPageWells();
    wells.clear();  //delete all related PageWell objects so we can re-create them from scratch

    page = pageHome.merge(page);
    wells = page.getPageWells();
    PageWell pageWell;

    // Now create a new PageWell and set up bi-directonal mapping with Page.  This part works great.
    pageWell = new PageWell();
    pageWell.setPage(page);
    wells.add(pageWell);

    // Now do the exact same thing with the PageComponentAttribute objects
    PageComponentAttribute pca = new PageComponentAttribute();
    pca.setPageWell(pageWell);
    pca.getPageWell().getPageComponentAttributes().add(pca);

    // Now save the Page
    page = pageHome.merge(page);
```

When I check the database, the FK in the **PageComponentAttribute** table is set to 0.  Again, I have temporarily removed the FK constraint from MySQL just to allow the record to save without an exception, but besides that, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you configure id in the PageComponentAttribute. How id is configured inside of BaseDAO?

Comment: PageComponentAttribute gets its id as AutoIncrement field in MySQL.  The id is fine.  The problem I have is with the foreign key from PageComponentAttribute to PageWell.  That foreign key value is always 0 in PageComponentAttribute.

Comment: But to answer your question, here is the id configuration for PageComponent Attribute =====  `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "page_component_attribute_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getPageComponentAttributeId()
 {
  return this.pageComponentAttributeId;
 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the unlikely chance that someone has made the same bone-headed mistake I've made, the problem was that the PageWell entity's primary key didn't have a Generation strategy.  I added that and it fixed my problem.

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try to do one of the things, or all:

**1)** Remove the cascade from the @ManyToOne. In general thats not a good idea to have it configured like that. It essentially makes sense only for @OneToMany and @OneToOne.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "page_well_id", nullable = false)
public PageWell getPageWell() {
    return this.pageWell;
}
```

**2)** Try using the Hibernate cascade configuration instead of the JPA one:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pageWell")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<PageComponentAttribute> getPageComponentAttributes() {
       return this.pageComponentAttributes;
}
```

There may be some small differences, see: [article](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/)

**3)** Not sure why you invoke `merge` twice on the `page` entity. I would just stick to one at the very end.

**4)** Last workaround that comes to my mind would be performing an explicit flush here:

```
pageWell = new PageWell();
pageWell.setPage(page);
wells.add(pageWell);
session.flush();
```

and then:

```
PageComponentAttribute pca = new PageComponentAttribute();
pca.setPageWell(pageWell);
pca.getPageWell().getPageComponentAttributes().add(pca);

session.merge(pageWell);
```

In theory, pageWell should have the primary already generated because of the flush and it should not be 0 anymore.

I wish i had a testing environment right now to test this properly.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried all of your suggestions but unfortunately it still is putting 0 in that foreign key. I am considering removing the relationship from Hibernate, and just add an id field that I set manually.  It is my last resort but I have been puzzled by this for hours.

Comment: That did not fix it, but you did nudge me in the direction of continuing to debug this rather than remove the relationship from Hibernate.    After I flush the session, I logged the PK value of pageWell, and it is 0.   So flush is somehow not forcing it to write the pageWell instance to generate an ID in time for me to add the child object.